# Put agents on a patch with the same variable value as the agents'

Tags: attributes, location, netlogo, patch, agent

I am loading my agents from a .csv file into NetLogo with the csv extension. These agents have as one of their attributes the ZIP-code from where they live.
The patches get as attributes the ZIP-code as well, loaded from a shapefile with the help of the GIS-extension.
What I want to achieve is that the agents are put directly into one of the patches with the matching ZIP-code.

What is working at the moment is, that the agents are walking until they are in the correct patch.

Here, a simplified version:

```
turtles-own [ turtle-location ]
patches-own [ location ]

to setup
 ca
 crt 10 [
  set turtle-location random 10
 ]  
ask patches [
 set location random 10 
]
end

to go
 ask turtles [
  location-turtles 
 ]
end

to location-turtles
 if (location != turtle-location)
  [ fd 2 ]
end
```

However, this is not really feasible and I am hoping for a solution where the agents are put directly on their correct location. Maybe with sprout/ hatch?

I thought about something like this (not working example):

```
ask turtles [
 move-to one-of patches with [ location = turtle-location ]  
]
```

But this piece of code gives me the error message:

> You can't use TURTLE-LOCATION in patch context, because
>   TURTLE-LOCATION is turtle-only.

Comment: What is not working with your final piece of code? Are you getting an error, or are they not moving, or ...

Comment: With the last piece of code (the move-to part) I get the error message: you can't use TURTLE-LOCATION in a patch context, because TURTLE-LOCATION is turtle-only (I added this in the text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ask turtles [
 move-to one-of patches with [ location = [turtle-location] of myself ]  
]
```

You need to let NetLogo know which turtle to get the turtle-location from.